# Dango 2.2 Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments

Tags: python, django, email, path

I have a problem with creating an account and activating it with the link sent in the email. The application is written in Django version 2.2.

After clicking the activation link, I receive a message:

`Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': '', 'token': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activate/(?P<uidb64>[^/]+)/(?P<token>[^/]+)/$']`

Code in urls.py

`path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', account.activate, name='activate'),`

Code in views.py, code for sign up and activate link. Signup is like a CBV and activate is like a FBV.

```
class Signup(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate your Spotted account'
            message = render_to_string('account/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user)
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('account_activation_sent')
        return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return render(request, 'account/account_activation_email.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account/account_activation_invalid.html')
```

In account/account_activation_email.html:

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},

Please click on the link below to confirm your registration:

http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

token.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six


class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.profile.email_confirmed)
        )


account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

Comment: You did not pass the `token` and `uid` to the context of the template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you mean in `Signup` view? I added also my token code.

Comment: @Webdev the offending line is this one: `return render(request, 'account/account_activation_email.html')`. There is no context provided as the third argument, while your template needs `uid` and `token` context variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `token` and `uid` as context to `render`:

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    ...

    context = {'uidb64':uidb64, 'token':token}
    return render(request, 'account/account_activation_email.html', context)
```

Comment: I did like you wrote and I got: `NoReverseMatch at /activate/NDI/5cs-f8555868ee0450f1e551/

Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': '', 'token': '5cs-343d23055a574944bd69'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activate/(?P<uidb64>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<token>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']`

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using Django 3.1 or above, the activation/password reset mechanism uses the SHA-256 hashing algorithm for tokens.
Your regexp is too strict.
you should use path instead url like the following as per the documentation.

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', ...)

path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', ...)
```

Details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature)

Comment: After converting the url from `url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', views.activate, name='activate'),`  TO `path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', ...)` worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue as well, I think there's a conflict with the types the url is looking for. To change this I simply changed the url values to string or string:UUID.